# Array item completion in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to accomplish an autocomplete of my own for matching array items while typing. So, I already have the logic done for matching what's being typed with what's in the array, but my question is related to displaying the proposed correction in the UITextView [like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY75D.jpg)

I was trying by splitting the text in the textview and replacing the last word into attributed strings, but that makes the proposed correction part of the actual contents. Any ideas of how this is accomplished in this app?

Answer (score 0):

What you currently do is good , when you set the text of the textView to attributed string make bool flag say it's name is `textEdited = true` with a string part that the user types say it's name **userStr** , when textView change method is triggered check that bool and according to it make the search if it's true proceed search with userStr if it's not proceed search with whole textView text , don't forget to make `textEdited= false` after every zero suggested result

Edit: regarding the cursor put a label under the textfield with the same font as the textView and make it's background darkGray , also make background of the textview transparent and every attributed string assign it to the label so plus part of the label will be shown and cursor will be as it is in the textView

Comment: I'm not sure your response has to do with the actual question I'm asking. I'm referring to the cursor position not being at the end.

Comment: Ahhhhh now I get what you're saying. And it works. Just gotta sync the scrolling of the views and it'll work perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: Another issue with this solution. If the textview behind wraps to a new line because of the content it's adding, the one on the top doesn't. Can't think of a perfect solution for that hrmmmm

Comment: you better make it one line also after a specific range of typing prevent search suggestion

Comment: Lol I'm trying to make a good app. Your suggestions are horrible.